# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot kill Chrome error with gallium and Docker

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, docker, selenium-chromedriver

After each scenario run our tests will do .quit() on the remote webdriver -

```
 Quits the driver and closes every associated window.
```

Running tests in docker containers (selenium hub and selenium-chrome version **3.14.0-gallium**

All of the tests are passing am getting a false negative because there are WebDriver Exceptions.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot kill Chrome
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591071 (0b695ff80972cc1a65a5cd643186d2ae582cd4ac),platform=Linux 4.14.67-coreos x86_64)
```

this is traced back to

```
python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 606, in quit
    self.execute(Command.QUIT)
```

the Chromedriver and chrome version are supposed to be compatible per documentation.

Comment: I used to get a lot of errors surrounding multiple chromedriver.exe processes running. Perhaps check your process list and see if there are more than one of these processes in there.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot kill Chrome
```

...implies that the **Chrome Browser** process was not **cleanly killed**.

---

### Analysis

As per [Zombie docker containers with chrome:59](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid/issues/137) this issue was pretty much evident with **selenoid** and **Docker**.

@IvanKrutov further confirmed that:

> Some issues with container removal still exist in Docker.

Where even trying to terminate a *zombie container* via **`docker rm -f`** doesn't seem to work and is confirmed to be a *Docker* issue.

---

### Solution

The only way to remove containers is to unmount filesystems, i.e. **remove `/var/lib/aufs and restart docker`**.

---

### tl;dr

From another perspective, as per [Chrome.exe still running in background, Chrome will not relaunch upon closing](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=337996):

- Chrome was not relaunching after closing Chrome.
- It was observed that **chrome.exe** is still running as a process in the *Task Manager*.
- Force closing Chrome.exe will allow Chrome to launch again, but otherwise Chrome will not launch.
- This issue seems to have re-surfaced again since **Google Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)** was released and is still continues to occur with **Google Chrome Version 70.x** which was recently pushed.

Comment: this analysis and solution has nothing to do with the question asked.